# Update Word (OpenXml) Content Control DataBinding programmatically - figure out XPath

Tags: c#, ms-word, metadata, openxml, openxml-sdk

**Update:** I solved the problem (with the help of some code from http://dbe.codeplex.com).

I have an issue where the metadata from my xml file is not being shown in the word file. It says `[MyFieldName]` rather than for example `3354`.

I figured out the reason for the quick part not working is its DataBinding.

- If I add a second quick part in Word and link it to the same document property it will show the metadata property just fine.
- If I now add the "working" DataBinding to the not working SdtBlock (SdtProperties) - the original control will work as well!

The following code fixes the second field control which has the invalid databinding.

```
DataBinding validBinding = null;
int count = 0;
foreach (OpenXmlElement openXmlElement in _contentControls)
{
    SdtProperties sdtProperties = openXmlElement.Elements<SdtProperties>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (sdtProperties == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Expected to find some sdt properties!");
    }

    Tag tag = sdtProperties.Elements<Tag>().FirstOrDefault();
    Console.WriteLine("\nProcessing SDT: {0}.", tag.Val);

    SdtContentRun sdtContent = openXmlElement.Elements<SdtContentRun>().Single();
    Console.WriteLine("Current value: " + sdtContent.InnerText);

    if (!sdtContent.InnerText.StartsWith("["))
    {
        // working control
        Console.WriteLine("Found working control");
        validBinding = sdtProperties.Elements<DataBinding>().Single();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Found not working control");
        DataBinding dataBinding = sdtProperties.Elements<DataBinding>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (dataBinding != null) dataBinding.Remove();

        dataBinding = new DataBinding();
        //dataBinding.PrefixMappings = validBinding.PrefixMappings;
        dataBinding.XPath = validBinding.XPath;
        dataBinding.StoreItemId = _customXmlPart.CustomXmlPropertiesPart.DataStoreItem.ItemId;
        sdtProperties.Append(dataBinding);
    }
}
```

**How do I create a new working DataBinding without creating a Quick Part in MS Word and copying its settings?**

```
DataBinding dataBinding = new DataBinding();
//dataBinding.PrefixMappings = validBinding.PrefixMappings;
//dataBinding.XPath = validBinding.XPath;
dataBinding.StoreItemId = _customXmlPart.CustomXmlPropertiesPart.DataStoreItem.ItemId;
```

**How do I get the XPath?**
The working databinding looks like that `<w:dataBinding w:xpath="/ns0:properties[1]/documentManagement[1]/ns6:MyFieldName[1]" w:storeItemID="{45C2489E-0875-4E37-AE02-CFEAFC2294DC}" />`

1. Why is there no PrefixMapping? Apparently it is not required.
2. Still it uses ns6:MyFieldName and I wonder where ns6 is even defined..?

**Why** `/ns6:MyFieldName[1]`? How do I know it is not `ns374`?

Answer (score 0):

The ns#: entries are references to the namespaces to which the nodes belong (namespace prefixes). These are assigned by Word at run-time and are unpredictable. This means that, at some point in the future, ns6 may not work.

Therefore you have to do some Namespace Management at run-time to get the prefix for a given namespace. You'll need to look up the namespace literals in order to do this.

ns0, for example, may be this one:
xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/custom-properties

If you've used a namespace in your Custom xml in the CustomXMLPart you're linking to the content controls, that could be the one assigned to ns6.